Trying to understand last part of the proof of normalized prime gap
We know that $$\liminf_{n\to\infty}{\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\log p_n}}=0.$$
I'm trying to figure out the proof and I have read a lot of documents, I asked a question here. Still I can't see what's going on. So I will try it one more time with more detail.
$$\mathscr{S}=\sum_{N<n\leq2N}\sum_{\mathscr{H}}\sum_{h_0 \leq h}(\theta(n+h_o)-\log{3N})\Lambda_R(n;\mathscr{H},k)^2$$
This guy is positive since
$$\sum_{h_0 \leq h}\theta(n+h_o)-\log{3N}>0 $$
Inequality holds when there are 2 primes in interval $(N,2N+h]$, hence $\min{p_{n+1}-p_n} \leq h$.
So we sieved a interval to find 2 successive primes and we found a bound.
After that,asymptotic calculation gives you if $\mathscr{S} > 0$
$$ (1) \ \frac{h}{\log{N}} > 1-\frac{2k}{2l+k+1}\frac{2l+1}{l+1}(\vartheta/2-\epsilon) $$
with choice of $l=[\sqrt{k}/2]$ we get
$$(2) \ \liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\log{p_n}}=\max(0,1-2\vartheta) $$
How did we get (2) from (1)? That's the only step that I can not understand. In all papers there isn't any extra explanation, just directly step. I feel like It's to embarrassing struggle.
Sorry for not giving any definition above. Here is what I'm talking about.

https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v170-n2-p10-p.pdf

https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0505300



In a comment under your previous question, "GH from MO" gave you the advice to look at Terry Tao's exposition of James Maynard's more recent work on primes in bounded intervals, which is both stronger and more streamlined than this older stuff you are looking at. Did you try doing that? It seemed like good advice to me.

@SamHopkins I didnt. I will but Im obssesed with this older stuff. Being not capable to understand this makes me crazy. It seems to easy but I cant understand.

You seem to mix up several things, so I try to straighten out things for you.
First of all, the sum considered by Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim is defined by (3.5) in their paper:
$$\mathscr{S}=\sum_{N<n\leq2N}\sum_{\mathscr{H}}\left(\sum_{1\leq h_0 \leq h}\theta(n+h_0)-\nu\log{3N}\right)\Lambda_R(n;\mathscr{H},l)^2,$$
where $\mathscr{H}$ runs through the admissible $k$-tuples from $\{1,2,\dotsc,h\}$, and $R=N^{\frac{\vartheta}{2}-\varepsilon}$. Note that the parentheses contain the $h_0$-sum minus $\nu\log 3N$, and the last argument of $\Lambda_R$ is not $k$ but $l$.
I will now review how Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim proved by analysing the above sum that
$$\liminf_{m\to\infty}\frac{p_{m+\nu}-p_m}{\log{p_m}}\leq\max(\nu-2\vartheta,0).\tag{3}$$
In proving this bound we can assume that $\vartheta\leq\nu/2$. Indeed, if $\vartheta>\nu/2$, then we simply replace $\vartheta$ by $\nu/2$. Let us also note that, since $\vartheta=1/2$ is admissible by the Bombieri-Vinogradov theorem, the bound $(3)$ implies in the special case $\nu=1$ that
$$\liminf_{m\to\infty}\frac{p_{m+1}-p_m}{\log{p_m}}=0.$$
Here are the details. Assume that the $k,l$ are fixed (along with $\nu,\vartheta$), and $h$ satisfies
$$\frac{h}{\log 3N}>\nu+\varepsilon-\frac{2k}{k+2l+1}\frac{2l+1}{l+1}\left(\frac{\vartheta}{2}-\varepsilon\right).\tag{4}$$
Then, by (3.8) in the Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim paper, $\mathscr{S}$ is positive for every sufficiently large $N>0$. In particular, for every sufficiently large $N>0$, there exists an integer $n\in[N,2N]$ such that
$$\sum_{1\leq h_0 \leq h}\theta(n+h_0)>\nu\log{3N};$$
hence there are more than $\nu$ primes in $[n,n+h]$. In particular, for every sufficiently large $N>0$, there exist $\nu+1$ consecutive primes
$$p_m,p_{m+1},\dotsc,p_{m+\nu}\in[N,2N+h]$$
satisfying the gap bound
$$\frac{p_{m+\nu}-p_m}{\log p_m}\leq\frac{h}{\log N}.\tag{5}$$
Now the question is how small can we make the right-hand side of $(5)$ numerically. For any $\varepsilon>0$, we can fix $k$ and $l=[\sqrt{k}/2]$ so that
$$\frac{2k}{k+2l+1}\frac{2l+1}{l+1}\left(\frac{\vartheta}{2}-\varepsilon\right)>2\theta-5\varepsilon.$$
Then, for $h=\lceil(\nu-2\vartheta+6\varepsilon)\log 3N\rceil$, the assumption $(4)$ is satisfied, hence the conclusion $(5)$ holds for every sufficiently large $N$ and a suitable large $m$ depending on $N$. We conclude by letting $N\to\infty$ (so that the corresponding $m$'s also tend to infinity) that
$$\liminf_{m\to\infty}\frac{p_{m+\nu}-p_m}{\log p_m}\leq\nu-2\vartheta+6\varepsilon.$$
As this holds for any $\varepsilon>0$, it follows that
$$\liminf_{m\to\infty}\frac{p_{m+\nu}-p_m}{\log p_m}\leq\nu-2\vartheta.$$

A personal question. Im new to sieve theory. I read a few papers and none of them were friendly to new players. I could have figured out everything you write by myself with extra effort. But equation (5) was the key step for me and I didnt see it. Is it up to my beginner mind or any other skill requirement?

@ArdaYonet I think that not seeing (5) shows a lack of experience in general. I mean, the goal is to find $\nu+1$ primes within a short interval, and in particular estimate the left-hand side of (5). Once we found $\nu+1$ primes as in the display above (5), it is most logical to see what these primes yield for the LHS of (5). We have an upper bound for $p_{m+\nu}-p_m$ and a lower bound for $\log p_m$, so bounding the LHS of (5) is straightforward. In fact we don't even need a precise lower bound for $\log p_m$. Simply, $p_m\asymp N$, hence $\log p_m=\log N+O(1)$. I continue in the next comment

@ArdaYonet In general, when studying a mathematical text, one needs to read in between the lines: what is the goal, what is the main strategy, why are the authors doing what they are doing.

@ArdaYonet Finally, as I said before, I recommend that you study the following blog entry by Terry Tao: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/11/19/polymath8b-bounded-intervals-with-many-primes-after-maynard/ It describes the proof of Maynard's much stronger theorem (sometimes called the Maynard-Tao theorem), which states that $\limsup_{m\to\infty}(p_{m+\nu}-p_m)<\infty$ and is based on an improved version of the Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim sieve. So in Maynard's proof $h$ does not grow with $N$, which is a shocker. The subject has cleaned up considerably, and Terry Tao explains things wonderfully.

Reading in between lines. Do I need to study on a such paper to understand it? I mean with that extra effort, or I have to be able to see them with one look. I know it depends on paper but what about this one?

@ArdaYonet Reading in between the lines means to think about the material that you are reading. You need to ask questions from yourself: what is the goal, what is the main strategy, why are the authors doing what they are doing? You cannot learn from papers how to think about mathematics and how to do mathematics. For that you need to think about mathematics and do mathematics yourself. If you are not experienced in doing mathematics, then solving high school olympiad problems (hundreds of them) might help.
